# Apply changes according to div id

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a div mapped so it would render any number of times according to data sent from the database. And on `componentDidMount` i'm getting an id. I want to change background color of the div which matches the id i'm getting from `componentDidMount` How can i do it?

**my code**

```
componentDidMount() {

        alert(this.props.voted_id);
}

render() {

        let {contents, submitvote, postId, voted_id} = this.props

        return (

            <div className="txt_vote_bar_div" id={contents.post_poll_content_id} style={{backgroundColor: this.state.vote_status ? '#0b97c4' : 'white'}}>
                <p className="txt_vote_choice" style={{color: this.state.vote_status ? '#FFFFFF' : '#6a6a6a'}}
                   onClick={() => {
                       this.handleClick(contents.post_poll_content_id);

                   }}> {contents.content} </p>
                <p className="txt_tot_votes"
                   style={{color: this.state.vote_status ? '#FFFFFF' : '#6a6a6a'}}> {contents.votes}%
                    (Votes:)</p>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

Basically what i want to do is if `this.props.voted_id` matches `contents.post_poll_content_id` , i want to change the background color of that div using states.

Comment: Just use regular JS to target the selector.

Comment: are you getting both **id** in the same div.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can simply get the element and change its style.

```
componentDidMount() {
  let el = document.getElementById(this.props.voted_id);
  if(el) {
     el.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
}
```

**Update**

Above approach manipulates DOM directly. It would be wise to let React handle actual DOM manipulations, unless absolute necessity.
To let React take care, you can make changes in JSX as:

```
<div className= {voted_id===content.post_poll_content_id ? "txt_vote_bar_div active" :  "txt_vote_bar_div"} id={content.post_poll_content_id} >

/CSS
.active {
  background-color:#0b97c4;
}
```

Comment: @Dev I don't think modifying the DOM is a good practice in React, because the beauty of React is to map data to UI, i.e. you just need to provide the state and React will figure out how to render the UI. Generally, changing the DOM directly breaks the rules of React. You should only touch the DOM directly when it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Dev if in the future, `style` is controlled by more React logic, touching dom directly will completely mess up the logic. In addition, React render UI based on `virtual DOM` which is an abstract layer on top of DOM, touching DOM directly is not desired

Comment: @Guigui. I agree!!

Answer (score 1):

Basically `this.props.voted_id` inside `componentDidMount` should equal to `this.props.voted_id` inside `render`.

How about

```
style={{backgroundColor:voted_id===contents.post_poll_content_id ? '#0b97c4' : 'white'}}
```

Comment: @CraZyDroiD changing DOM directly is by no means a good practice. Please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: Thanks i've already accepted another answer. I will upvote your answer.